# How to add turtle module to Pyodide?

Tags: reactjs, pyodide

I tried using turtle functions in web(pyodide) it was not working then i saw that they have removed some inbuilt module from pyodide turtle is one of it.I want turtle to work on web
how can i ?

Answer (score 2):

The native tutle module from stdlib is based on tkinter which Pyodide doesn't support.

However, there is a turtle re-implementation for Brython which was adapted for Pyodide in the [Basthon project here](https://framagit.org/basthon/basthon-kernel/-/tree/master/packages/kernel-python3/src/modules/turtle).

You can ask maintainers to release it as a wheel so that it could be installed with micropip (or create a wheel out if it yourself).